# How to listen to a port in cloverleaf using JMeter to receive messages and get them as response into JMeter Listeners?

Tags: jmeter, listener, receiver

I have tried using Java Requests, TCP Samplers, JSR223 but nothing seems to work, a connection is established but no message is shown in the Listeners.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) or [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) it's **you** who needs to get the response, convert it into a byte array or a string and set it as a [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html).

See JavaDoc for all available functions (you're interested in [setResponseData()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseData(byte%5B%5D)) mainly) and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other most commonly used [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) classes